# VueJS v-for loop with condition on previous element

Tags: vue.js

This is about chat messages. I have this VueJS template :

```
<div class="container" v-for="(m,i) in messages">
    <p>{{ m.text }}</p>
    <span :class="cssAlignement(m.sender_name,i)">{{ m.sender_name }} - {{ m.date }}</span>
</div>
```

in data :

```
alignement: 'left',
messages : [
{sender_name: 'A', text: 'lorem ipsumA', date: '...'},
{sender_name: 'B', text: 'lorem ipsumB', date: '...'},
{sender_name: 'C', text: 'lorem ipsumC', date: '...'},
{sender_name: 'C', text: 'lorem ipsumCbis', date: '...'},
{sender_name: 'B', text: 'lorem ipsumBbis', date: '...'},
...
]
```

I want to add the css 'left' or 'right' but changing only if the sender_name changes. So i have to check the previous element.

I tried with this method :

```
cssAlignement: function(name, index) {
    if(index>0 && name!==this.messages[index-1].sender_name) {
        this.alignement = this.alignement==='left'?'right':'left';
        }
    return this.alignement;
    },
```

But i get the error

```
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

What is the way to do ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do not mutate component state during the render, this line is the culprit: `this.alignment = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

As Decade Moon said in the comments - do not mutate state while rendering. Also there are numerous possible proper solutions. It's not about "what is the previous one" but "if I am the sender" if I get you correctly? :)

So I would prepare the data upfront, let's say on `mounted` and add properties "left" or "right" to each message.

Or directly compare my user name with sender user name inline.

Or even better - call a method to add css class that handles all of the checks - you might want to style it differently in the future so simply adjusting the class is good enough.

It's all about data and you have all the flexibility in the world, so don't be afraid to use it and get stuck into some situations - solve them in other ways.